# Regex string with grouping?

Tags: ruby, regex, grouping, regex-group

I see in the documentation I'm able to do:

```
/\$(?<dollars>\d+)\.(?<cents>\d+)/ =~ "$3.67" #=> 0
puts dollars #=> prints 3
```

I was wondering if this would be possible:

```
string = "\$(\?<dlr>\d+)\.(\?<cts>\d+)"
/#{Regexp.escape(string)}/ =~ "$3.67"
```

I get:

```
`<main>': undefined local variable or method `dlr' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: thanks for re-editing... was trying to do it again but couldn't.. now know why :)

Comment: Since I can't reply here it is: 
Looked more and more and found exactly what I needed.

Here is the example:

string = "\$(\?<dlr>\d+)\.(\?<cts>\d+)"<br>
m = /#{string}/.match("aaaabbbb")<br>
puts m["dlr"] <br>
puts m["cts"] <br>  

<br>
Thanking myself! :)

Comment: What you posted will not actually match: `string = "\$(\?<dlr>\d+)\.(\?<cts>\d+)"; m = /#{string}/.match("$3.67")` returns `nil`, because the dollar is not escaped (see my answer). You are matching for a string that begins with end of line ;-).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your approach. First of all, let's look at your string:

```
string = "\$(\?<dlr>\d+)\.(\?<cts>\d+)"
```

You escape the dollar sign with `"\$"`, but that is the same as just writing `"$"`, consider:

```
"\$" == "$"
#=> true
```

To actually end up with the string "backslash followed by dollar" you would need to write `"\\$"`. The same thing applies to the decimal character classes, you would have to write `"\\d"` to end up with the correct string.

The question marks on the other hand are actually part of the regex syntax, so you do not want to escape these at all. I recommend using single quotes for your original string, because that makes the input much easier:

```
string = '\$(?<dlr>\d+)\.(?<cts>\d+)'
#=> "\\$(?<dlr>\\d+)\\.(?<cts>\\d+)"
```

The next issue is with `Regexp.escape`. Take a look at what regular expression it produces with the above string:

```
string = '\$(?<dlr>\d+)\.(?<cts>\d+)'
Regexp.escape(string)
#=> "\\\\\\$\\(\\?<dlr>\\\\d\\+\\)\\\\\\.\\(\\?<cts>\\\\d\\+\\)"
```

That's one level too much escaping. `Regexp.escape` can be used when you want to match the literal characters that are contained in the string. For example, the escaped regex above will match the source string itself:

```
/#{Regexp.escape(string)}/ =~ string
#=> 0                                   # matches at offset 0
```

Instead, you can use `Regexp.new` to treat the source as an actual regular expression.

The last issue is then how you access the match result. Obviously, you are getting a `NoMethodError`. You might think that the match result is stored in local variables called `dlr` and `cts`, but that is not the case. You have two options to access the match data:

- Use `Regexp.match`, it will return a `MatchData` object as result
- Use `regexp =~ string` and then access the last match data with the global variable `$~`

I prefer the former, because it is easier to read. The full code would then look like this:

```
string = '\$(?<dlr>\d+)\.(?<cts>\d+)'
regexp = Regexp.new(string)

result = regexp.match("$3.67")
#=> #<MatchData "$3.67" dlr:"3" cts:"67">

result[:dlr]
#=> "3"

result[:cts]
#=> "67"
```